# Are there any issues I need to be aware of, migrating a WCF service from .NET 3.5 to 4.0?

Tags: wcf

I wrote a WCF service back in 2009, which uses net.tcp.  I used VS 2008, .NET 3.5.  Now I'm working on a new WPF app using VS 2010 and .NET 4.0, that will consume my WCF service.  In working on this, I've discovered that I'm going to have to make several changes to the WCF service.  Since I've got to do that I thought I might as well upgrade it to .NET 4.0, the only concern is, do I need to be aware of any changes that I need to take into account?  (At this point the only app that will be using the WCF service is this new WPF client app, so I won't be impacting anything else.)

Comment: There are some things you might like to take advantage of (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee354381.aspx) but I don't believe there are any breaking changes.

Comment: Just go for it.  You should be ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I concur with everyone else, however in my experience `netTcpBinding` is more trouble than it's worth.  Too many configuration headaches, and even after I dealt with all of those it turns out some of my clients were using proxy servers that had to have exceptions added to their network.  This was the real killer.

I ended up redoing my service using `wsHttpBinding` on port 80 instead, and instead of worrying about callbacks I just had my clients ping the server in intervals looking for data.

Comment: Really, how interesting.  I've written a couple of WCF services, most using wsHttpBinding, but in this particular case the WCF service was going to be transferring a lot of data over the wire.  Since it is on premise, I thought it best to use TCP instead of HTTP, since TCP should be faster.

Comment: @Rod -- I would assume TCP would be faster as well.  It really depends on your network architecture.  In my case we are using a service that consumers are using via a WPF Clickonce application.  Port 80 is pretty much the only port that is likely to be working for 99% of people.